# Highlight multiple search words in string

Tags: php, mysql

There's a thing in my country called 'Rut', that is like an ID number, for every person. Rut number format is "12.345.678-K" (K can also be a number).

So, I made an ajax live search form to show people from my database in a table, and when people type 12345678k it turns to 12.345.678-k and search that Rut in the database ($q is the search word).

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE rut LIKE '%$ruts%' OR rut LIKE '%$ruts2%' OR rut LIKE '%$q%'
```

Format:

```
//Rut format
if(strlen($q)==3){
    // 123 -> 12.3
    $ruts = substr_replace($q, '.', 2, -1);
}elseif(strlen($q)==4){
    // 1234 -> 12.34
    $ruts = substr_replace($q, '.', 2, -2);
}elseif(strlen($q)==5){
    // 12345 -> 12.345
    $ruts = substr_replace($q, '.', 2, -3);
}elseif(strlen($q)==6){
    // 123456 -> 12.3456
    // 12.3456 -> 12.345.6
    $ruta = substr_replace($q, '.', 2, -4);
    $ruts = substr_replace($ruta, '.', 6, -1);
}elseif(strlen($q)==7){
    // 1234567 -> 12.34567
    // 12.34567 -> 12.345.67
    $ruta = substr_replace($q, '.', 2, -5);
    $ruts = substr_replace($ruta, '.', 6, -2);
}elseif(strlen($q)==8){
    // 12345678 -> 12.345.678
    // 12.345678 -> 12.345.678
    $ruta = substr_replace($q, '.', 2, -6);
    $ruts = substr_replace($ruta, '.', 6, -3);
}elseif(strlen($q)==9){
    // 12345678k -> 12.345678k
    // 12.345678k -> 12.345.678k
    // 12.345.678k -> 12.345.678-k
    $ruta = substr_replace($q, '.', 2, -7);
    $rutb = substr_replace($ruta, '.', 6, -4);
    $ruts = substr_replace($rutb, '-', 10, -1);
}else{
    $ruts = $q;
}
```

I also made str_replace(), to highlight the results while I'm typing.

```
$highlightrut = str_replace("$ruts", "<span style='color:red'>$ruts</span>", $output['rut']);
```

The problem is that, there is another diferent Rut format (1.234.567-K), and I already did the format conversion

```
//Rut format 2 (1.234.567-K)
if(strlen($q)==2){
    // 12 -> 1.2
    $ruts2 = substr_replace($q, '.', 1, -1);
}elseif(strlen($q)==3){
    // 123 -> 1.23
    $ruts2 = substr_replace($q, '.', 1, -2);
}elseif(strlen($q)==4){
    // 1234 -> 1.234
    $ruts2 = substr_replace($q, '.', 1, -3);
}elseif(strlen($q)==5){
    // 12345 -> 1.2345
    // 1.2345 -> 1.234.5
    $ruta2 = substr_replace($q, '.', 1, -4);
    $ruts2 = substr_replace($ruta2, '.', 5, -1);
}elseif(strlen($q)==6){
    // 123456 -> 1.23456
    // 1.23456 -> 1.234.56
    $ruta2 = substr_replace($q, '.', 1, -5);
    $ruts2 = substr_replace($ruta2, '.', 5, -2);
}elseif(strlen($q)==7){
    // 1234567 -> 1.234567
    // 1.234567 -> 1.234.567
    $ruta2 = substr_replace($q, '.', 1, -6);
    $ruts2 = substr_replace($ruta2, '.', 5, -3);
}elseif(strlen($q)==8){
    // 1234567k -> 1.234567k
    // 1.234567k -> 1.234.567k
    // 1.234.567k -> 1.234.567-k
    $ruta2 = substr_replace($q, '.', 1, -7);
    $rutb2 = substr_replace($ruta2, '.', 5, -4);
    $ruts2 = substr_replace($rutb2, '-', 9, -1);
}else{
    $ruts2 = $q;
}
```

But I don't know how to highlight the results in the same string.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by highlighting the results in the same string? You have `$rut2` and `$rut` right? Use a flag indicating which format matched and set $highlightrut accordingly. Por cierto, extrano a Chile po! :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean in the same cell. The query results show in a table, and the Rut sesult is shown in a cell. So, when I search "1256" it really searching for "12.56" so, if the rut is "12.563.589-K" that ("12.56") will highlight. I want to do the same with the other rut format. Also, how do I use a flag? Saludos desde Chile!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store all Rut numbers in a format like 12345678k in your database?

Comment: The database was already done, all the Rut are saved like that, I just imported the table in my database :(

Comment: Maybe you can just create a second column and populate it with the rut without "." and "-". It will also help your code to be simpler.

Comment: Yes, I should do that second column, but I don't want to un-format 383 different Rut numbers

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, thanks all for your support.
Here's the code:

```
if(preg_match('~('.$ruts.')~', $output['rut'])) {
        $highlightrut = str_replace("$ruts", "<span style='color:red'>$ruts</span>", $output['rut']);
    }elseif(preg_match('~('.$ruts2.')~', $output['rut'])) {
        $highlightrut =str_replace("$ruts2", "<span style='color:red'>$ruts2</span>", $output['rut']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can str_replace a second time but now on $highlightrut var. You'll have both highlights on the string

```
$highlightrut = str_replace("$ruts", "<span style='color:red'>$ruts</span>", $output['rut']);
$highlightrut = str_replace("$ruts2", "<span style='color:red'>$ruts2</span>", $highlightrut);
```

Or

```
$highlightrut = str_replace(array("$ruts","$ruts2"), array("<span style='color:red'>$ruts</span>","<span style='color:red'>$ruts2</span>"), $output['rut']);
```

Comment: But if I search "50" and Rut number is "5.050.658-K" it will highlight the four numbers at the beginning, right?

Comment: Yes, if your search disconsider the dots, they will

Comment: That's the problem, I can't disconsider the dots yet

Comment: So, in this case your search will only highlight the second 50